# Key-Value mapping in R

Tags: r, list, key-value-coding

I would like to categorize the cities in city_1, city_2 etc in my dataset.. but using a key value mapping. For example I would like to retrieve "city_1" giving 4059 as value and so on..

Do you have some suggestions on how can I solve this?
Thank you!

This is the list:

```r
zip_codes <- list("city_1" =c(4000, 4001, 4005, 4009, 4010, 4018, 4019, 4020, 4030, 4031, 4051, 4052, 4053, 4054, 4055, 4056, 4057, 4058, 4059))
```

```
|__A____|___B___|
|__4000_|_city_1|
|__4009_|_city_1|
|__4059_|_city_1|
|__4059_|_city_1|
|__4565_|_city_2|
```

So for example, I have a dataset, in which zip codes such as the ones above appear in the columns and I would like to map to which place each of those zip_code belongs. I want to make column "B" from the zip code list.
I was thinking to a key-values mapping, but maybe in R it is not the best way....Do you have better ideas?

Comment: What is the logic for retreiving 'city_1' as 4059

Comment: Can you please update with a full reproudcible example.  Are you trying to replace the columns with the value in zip_codes.  Here the `City_1` is showed with multiple values.  Or is it a column in your dataset andd do you have another key/value pair list

Answer (score 1):

We can use `enframe` from `tidyverse`

```
 library(tibble)
 library(dplyr)
 ref_df <- enframe(zip_codes) %>%
             unnest(c(value))
```

and then we can extract with

```
as.character(ref_df$name[ref_df$value == 4059])
```

Comment: what if I have 4009? I would need something that works with all of them randomly distributed in a dataframe

Comment: @flavinsky your example is not clear.  From the example, i thought you wanted the last value

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I added more explanations to make my post clearer.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a key-value pair dataframe from the list using `stack`.

```
ref_df <- stack(zip_codes)
```

and then it is easy to extract any city name using the zip code.

```
as.character(ref_df$ind[ref_df$values == 4059])
#[1] "city_1"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want key-value pairs, then you can do it with a named vector.  For example,

```r
df <- data.frame(A = c(4000, 4009, 4059, 4565), 
                 B = c("city_1", "city_1", "city_1", "city_2"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

keyvalue <- df$B
names(keyvalue) <- df$A

# Look up 4059:

keyvalue[as.character(4059)]
#>     4059 
#> "city_1"
```

Note that your original table has 4059 in it twice.  This solution assumes that was a typo:  you shouldn't have the same code more than once.  I'm not even sure what that would mean in terms of your original problem.